# How to get a text to display on vba when a button is pressed?

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement

```
 Sum = Application.Sum(Range(Cells(12, 3), Cells(12, 82)))
 If Sum = 0 Then
    Enter = "Enter a value for  E"
    Exit Sub
 End If
```

So I am trying to get "Enter a value for E to pop up when the button is clicked. So far when the statement is true, nothing happens.

Comment: You can use `MsgBox Enter` after the line `Enter = "Enter a value for  E"`

Comment: `Application.InputBox`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `MsgBox Enter` after the line `Enter = "Enter a value for E"`:

```
Sum = Application.Sum(Range(Cells(12, 3), Cells(12, 82)))
If Sum = 0 Then
    Enter = "Enter a value for  E"
    MsgBox Enter
    Exit Sub
End If
```